# Sachs and Wu's General Relativity for Mathematicians

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

I am trying to study "religiously" the book by Sachs and Wu, but I am finding the exercises very much of a challenge. Does anyone know if there exists a source for solutions one can consult when stuck? (Apologies in advance if this question might be violating the Stackexchange criteria for posing queries.)

Comment: You can always ask here instead when you're stuck. I found Barrett O'neill's Semi-Riemannian Geometry more readable and complete(?). But it just my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Yes, I think I will first grapple with O'Neill's book. I had not considered O'Neill's book deeply enough, since I thought the emphasis there was maybe on the geometry, but I agree it it looks broader or at least more up-to-date even with the relativity part. I might return to Sachs and Wu later on.

Comment: Did you have ever read any GR books before ? If not then starting with Sachs and Wu probably not a good idea.

Comment: Yes, I have studied Schutz's GR book, and Riemannian Geometry using do Carmo's book. Thanks.